# When initializing a new repository in git. Do I first change into the directory I want files from?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

When I enter "git init" into my command prompt to develop a repository do I then need to provide a specific path into the directory I want it tracking files from? Would I be able to just navigate to that directory, then initiate that command? Also, after typing "git init" how do I name that repository? All help greatly appreciated, I'm very new. Thank you

Comment: Likely you need [git clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) but it'd be better to read a [tutorial](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository) first

Answer (score 1):

When you *git init*, you are initialising a new repository in your local machine. When you want to name the repository you simply `git init "name of repo"` if you're in the desired directory, otherwise you can specify the directory with `git init path/to/directory/name-of-repo` and git will make a new folder called *name-of-repo*.

Some more concise tips here: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository/

Enjoy using git!